# Использование WinSock

Tags: winsock, c++

Хочу уйти от компоненты Indy, используя сокеты. Изучаю много инфы, и в связи с этим у меня возник вопрос - какую версию сокета лучше использовать в моём случае?
Мне нужно отправлять на сервер по UDP протоколу команды вида "\xff\xff\xff\xff getstatus", и принимать буфер, причем принимать так, что бы принимался пакет со строкой внутри, и к этой строке больше ничего не прибавлялось (как это было с Indy-компонентой. Там задавался большой буфер, и по таймеру первый раз когда шел прием, то к пришедшей строке прибавлялся мусор, похоже, для забивки буфера. Естественно, такую строчку невозможно было правильно в дальнейшем распарсить).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотя в принципе мне нужно будет реализовать и пинг, а Raw-сокеты с ICMP доступны только в winsock2. Буду юзать его. Вопрос закрыт.